# Maven local repository is not working at all for thirdparties jars

Tags: maven, maven-2, maven-3

I'm new in this maven stuff and I'm having big problems with the local repository.

I want to add a third party jar, the deal with this is that I have something like :

```
        <dependency>
            <groupId>com.thirdParty</groupId>
            <artifactId>thirdParty</artifactId>
            <version>4.0.2</version>
            <scope>system</scope>
            <systemPath>${basedir}/lib/thirdParty_4_0_2/thirdParty.jar</systemPath>
        </dependency>
```

And It's working awesome, but I got some warnings and I want to remove this warnings.

```
[WARNING] Some problems were encountered while building the effective model for com.thirdParty.connector:thirdParty:mule-module:1.0
[WARNING] 'dependencies.dependency.systemPath' for com.thirdParty:thirdParty:jar should not point at files within the project directory, ${basedir}/lib/thirdParty_java_client_4_0_2/thirdParty.jar will be unresolvable by dependent projects @ line 239, column 20
```

So instead of doing that I heard that I can have a maven local repository and add all my third party jars there and then add a repository in my XML and then just called them.

So I have something like :

```
    <repository>
        <id>local-maven-repository</id>
        <name>local-maven-repository</name>
        <releases>
            <enabled>true</enabled>
            <checksumPolicy>ignore</checksumPolicy>
        </releases>
        <snapshots>
            <enabled>false</enabled>
        </snapshots>
        <url>file://${project.basedir}/../../local-maven-repository</url>
    </repository>
```

And Inside of local-maven-repository I have something like :

```
local-maven-repository
|-- com 
|   |-- thirdparty
|       |-- sdk
|           | -- 4.0.0
|                | thirdParty-4.0.0.jar
|                | thirdParty-4.0.0.pom
```

And I'm getting this error.

```
[ERROR] Failed to execute goal on project thirdParty: Could not resolve dependencies for project com.thirdParty.connector:thirdParty:mule-module:1.0: Failure to find com.thirdParty:thirdParty:jar:4.0.2 in file:///Users/moises.vega/Developer/Telstra/telstra-thunder/connectors/thirdParty/../../local-maven-repository was cached in the local repository, resolution will not be reattempted until the update interval of local-maven-repository has elapsed or updates are forced -> [Help 1]
```

Could someone point me to the right direction to tackle this problem?

Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

Don't use system dependencies. Don't try to create a repository in disk.

If you need something that is not in Maven central, then (preferably) deploy Nexus or Archiva or Artifactory and deploy it there. If you can't do that, put it in ~/.m2/repository with install:install-file.

Answer (score 0):

From a point of view of maven good practices, both solutions are bad.

Personally, I would use the first solution you mentioned, and live with the warning.
Maven complains (with some reason) that if you have a dependent project, that project won't be able to find the jar file, as the ${project.basedir} will resolve to a different directory. And this would apply to both solutions, even if you manage to make the second work.

If you don't have a local maven repository (such as nexus or artifactory), I think the second *best* solution might be to write a script that runs the `mvn install:install-file`, as as part of your build process you need to run that script and then run any of the maven comands.
This can also be done from a pom file, but it's a bit tricky and requires more setup. You would need a multi-module project, and the first module to be run should run the install plugin, to install the jar. You can do this by making all the other submodules depend on the module that installs the dependency.